# syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ':' Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I'd like to remove this part : 
`"company.html?#{token_url}&company=#{URI.encode(current_company.trylive_name)}"` but an error appears **syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ':'**

```
@iframe_statistics_url = "#{Gaston.amazon.cloudfront.host}/trylive_dashboard/iframe/#{current_user.has_role?(:administrator) ? "companies.html?#{admin_token_url}" : "company.html?#{token_url}&company=#{URI.encode(current_company.trylive_name)}"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use double quotes(`"`) inside double quotes. You need to escape those quotes:

```
"Hello, "are you there?" # doesn't make sense in Ruby
"Hello, \"are you there?" # escaped double quotes inside the string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
val = current_user.has_role?(:administrator) ? "companies.html?#{admin_token_url}" : "company.html?#{token_url}&company=#{URI.encode(current_company.trylive_name)}"

@iframe_statistics_url = "#{Gaston.amazon.cloudfront.host}/trylive_dashboard/iframe/}#{val}"
```

**Or**

```
g = "https://www.google.co.in/"

q = %[helo #{"world #{g}"}]

=> "helo world https://www.google.co.in/"
```

Try it

```
@iframe_statistics_url = %[#{Gaston.amazon.cloudfront.host}/trylive_dashboard/iframe/companies.html?#{current_user.has_role?(:administrator) ? admin_token_url : "#{token_url}&company=#{URI.encode(current_company.trylive_name)}"}]
```

Comment: @iframe_statistics_url = "#{Gaston.amazon.cloudfront.host}/trylive_dashboard/iframe/#{current_user.has_role?(:administrator) ? "companies.html?#{admin_token_url}" : "company.html?#{token_url}&company=#{URI.encode(current_company.trylive_name)}"}"

Comment: Do you need single line?

Comment: i explained the issue in other comment above

Comment: Just check ternary operator in ruby "puts 1 ? 2 : 3   # => 2" the operation not completed

Comment: i just need to keep   @iframe_statistics_url = "#{Gaston.amazon.cloudfront.host}/trylive_dashboard/iframe/#{current_user.has_ro‌​le?(:administrator) ? "companies.html?#{admin_token_url}" and remove : "company.html?#{token_url}&company=#{URI.encode(current_company.trylive_name)}" and when i remove it it results an error

Comment: try @iframe_statistics_url = "#{Gaston.amazon.cloudfront.host}/trylive_dashboard/iframe/companies.html?#{admin_token_url}"

Comment: the meaning of 
current_user.has_role?(:administrator) ? 'companies.html?#{admin_token_url}' : 'company.html?#{token_url}&company=#{URI.encode(current_company.trylive_name)}
 is ------
a = "3"     /  puts a == "3" ? true : false
---

Answer (score 0):

@VtrKanna

```
@iframe_statistics_url = "#{Gaston.amazon.cloudfront.host}/trylive_dashboard/iframe/#{current_user.has_role?(:administrator) ? "companies.html?#{admin_token_url}" : "company.html?#{token_url}&company=#{URI.encode(current_company.trylive_name)}"}"
```

this is work fine 
but my problem is just to keep this part

```
@iframe_statistics_url = "#{Gaston.amazon.cloudfront.host}/trylive_dashboard/iframe/#{current_user.has_role?(:administrator) ? "companies.html?#{admin_token_url}"}"
```

this is result an error

Comment: you should edit your question instead of answering :)